# Desktop notifications for phone calls on iOS 7

Tags: macos, iphone, notifications

Is it possible to send notifications to my Mountain Lion desktop when my iPhone receives a phone call?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Without a jailbreak what you ask is definitely not possible right now.

With a jailbreak there seems to be some apps that can send notifications like [GrowlNotifier](http://www.ijailbreak.com/cydia/growlnotifier-cydia-tweak/).

Answer (score 4):

[**Connect**](https://itunes.apple.com/us/app/connect/id730953769?mt=12) can show notifications on your Mac when you get a phone call. It connects to your device over Bluetooth and will 'ring' on your Mac. You can also make/receive calls on your Mac. No jailbreak required — works over public APIs for Bluetooth.

[image: Connect — Phone Call]

Comment: This does not answer the question. The app is for Maverick or later.

Answer (score 1):

With OS X Yosemite and iOS 8, you can use [Continuity](https://www.apple.com/osx/preview/mac-and-ios/) to be notified of incoming calls and answer them on the Mac.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

I use Phone Amego to do that very thing on both OS X 10.7.5 and OS X 10.9.4. No jailbreak required. Works like a charm over bluetooth, and also allows logging/sending SMS.